# Does Craft Support MariaDB?

Tags: database

I am hoping craft supports MariaDB. Also, since version 10, InnoDB transaction engine in MariaDB has been replaced with XtraDB. Will this work with Craft?

Answer (score 9):

**Update:**
Craft 3 officially supports MariaDB 5.5+ now. https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/requirements.html

---

Not officially, no.  MariaDB is supposed to a "drop-in" replacement for MySQL, but there are clearly areas where it is not 1:1 compatible with MySQL: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

We've seen some installations using MariaDB where a query would actually return *incorrect* results and the same MySQL query on the same database returns that data correctly.

Comment: Thats unfortunate for me. I was planning to setup a local dev environment on my synology NAS box. It comes with all the requirements - Apache web server, php, phpadmin and until recently msql. It has replaced mysql in a recent software update with MariaDB. I wonder if the problems you mention above are resolved in version 10 of MariaDB ( They seem to have been existent on version 5 - way back).

Comment: Entirely possible. We saw a slew of MariaDB related support tickets maybe 8-12 months ago, but really haven't seen one in awhile.

Comment: I wonder where I can poll the craft community to see if anyone has successfully used it with MariaDB 10 without any hiccups.

Comment: Either on Twitter with the #craftcms hashtag or the G+ group buildwithcraft.com/gplus should do it.

Comment: Any update on official support on the latest versions @BradBell? Or plans for it?

Comment: @RussBack no word on official support, but we haven't seen any issues with people running it in quite some time.

Comment: From my experience, craft runs much slower with big amount of data (40k categories in my case) on MariaDB, had to switch to MySQL 5.7.